# DevExtreme override css of dxButton

Tags: html, css, devextreme

I have the following dxButton element.

```
<div class="dx-field-value" data-bind="dxButton: { text: name, onClick: $root.name }"></div>
```

The text of the button is being assigned via the variable `name`. Now, I want the button text to be always `uppercase` for this **specific element** only.

I have tried setting an id and a class for it, and create custom css however it did not work. I have also tried inline styling as follows:

```
<div class="dx-field-value" style="text-transform: uppercase;" data-bind="dxButton: { text: 'Text' }"></div>
```

Comment: Why don't you go `<div class="dx-field-value" data-bind="dxButton: { text: name.toUppercase(), onClick: $root.name }"></div>`?

Comment: @connexo hi thanks for your comment. This won't work because there is already a css rule that forces all button text to be lowercase. I just want this to be inversed for this specific button.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `dx-button-text` class name to customize your button text.

Make all buttons lowercase:

```
.dx-button-text {
    text-transform: lowercase;
}
```

Then, add a specific css class to the button you want to be uppercase:

```
<div data-bind="dxButton: { text: name }" class="uppercase"></div>
```

And apply the following rule:

```
.uppercase .dx-button-text {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/atmg63q2/).